# Connect to daemon docker installed in another local machine

Tags: docker, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ idea editor and I want to connect the docker plugin to a docker daemon installed in another machine in the same local network.
But the problem is the connection is failed with the exception `java.net.SocketTimeoutException`

ps: The "expose daemon on tcp.." is enabled

How can I solve that, please?

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to connect outside IDE?

Comment: Share the docker run command which you're using

Comment: Unless you're absolutely 100% confident you've set it up correctly, the remote Docker API is a potential security disaster – anyone who can connect to the Docker socket can trivially root the host.  I'd find another way to achieve your goal here.

Comment: @y.bedrov, when i tried to use the telnet <IP address> <Port> command, i was able to connect to other ports such as the port of my java applications installed on the machine, but i didn't managed to connect with daemon docker port.

Comment: @Ashok i didn't use any docker command, i tried to connect directly through the editor .. but when i did the same with the editor installed in the machine i want to connect to, the connection is established successfully.

Comment: @DavidMaze can you tell me how please?

Comment: ssh to the remote host and run your container there, using `docker run`; do local development without involving Docker at all; if you've configured the remote system to allow unauthenticated connections to the Docker socket on port 2375, consider whether it's been compromised and needs to be reinstalled.

Comment: Do you use any antivirus/firewall that might block connections?